# Como jogar valores recuperados de banco em inputs usando o FullCalendar

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

Estou com uma dificuldade em jogar valores recuperados de um banco para campos de um formulário para posterior edição, já li a documentação, já procurei exemplos e mesmo assim não consegui, já até conferi um post que tem aqui mesmo no SO.
Para exibir as informações quando o calendário é chamado está certo, o script que faz isso é esse.
A página que lista os eventos: `pListaAgendamento.php`

```
// AGENDAMENTOS
$sqlAgenda = "SELECT * FROM dvsAgendaSala";
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sqlAgenda);
$stm->execute();    
$ResAgenda = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
// FECHANDO A CONSULTA
$stm->closeCursor(); 

$eventos = [];

foreach ($ResAgenda as $ResAgendamento) {

    $eventos[] = [
        'id' => $ResAgendamento->Id, 
        'idsalareuniao' => $ResAgendamento->IdSalaReuniao, 
        'title' => $ResAgendamento->Motivo,         
        'start' => $ResAgendamento->DataHoraInicial, 
        'end' => $ResAgendamento->DataHoraFinal, 
        'tipo' => $ResAgendamento->IdTipo,
        'FoneResponsavel' => $ResAgendamento->FoneResponsavel,
        'EmailResponsavel' => $ResAgendamento->FoneResponsavel,
        ];

}
```

Os valores `ID`, `title`, `start` e `end` que são pegos do próprio calendário são jogados nos inputs correspondente corretamente, mas o `FoneResponsavel`, `EmailResponsavel` e `idsalareuniao` não.
O que tentei fazer pode ser visto aqui na página `personalizado.js`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    // DATA E HORA ATUAL 
    var dataatual = new Date();
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        locale: 'pt-br',
        plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        defaultDate: dataatual,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        events: 'pListaAgendamento.php',
                 FoneResponsavel: FoneResponsavel,
                 EmailResponsavel: EmailResponsavel,
        extraParams: function () {
            return {
                cachebuster: new Date().valueOf()
            };
        },
        // DISPARA EVENTO QUANDO USUÁRIO CLICA NO LINK
        eventClick: function (info) {
            // RESGATE DAS INFORMAÇÕES DO PROJETO VINDO DA PÁGINA list_eventos.php
            // info CONTÊM AS INFORMAÇÕES DA API
            info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); 
            console.log(info.event);
            // TEXTO PARA VISUALIZAR DETALHES
            $('#visualizar #Id').text(info.event.id);
            $('#visualizar #Motivo').text(info.event.title);
            // VALORES PARA EDIÇÃO
            $('#visualizar #Id').val(info.event.id);            
            $('#visualizar #Motivo').val(info.event.title);
            $('#visualizar #Telefone').val(event.FoneResponsavel);
            $('#visualizar #Email').val(event.EmailResponsavel);
            // FORMATA A DATA PARA O PATRÃO PORTUGUÊS - INFORMAÇÃO
            $('#visualizar #DataInicial').text(info.event.start.toLocaleString());
            $('#visualizar #DataFinal').text(info.event.end.toLocaleString());
            // FORMATA A DATA PARA O PATRÃO PORTUGUÊS - INPUT´S
            $('#visualizar #DataInicial').val(info.event.start.toLocaleString());
            $('#visualizar #DataFinal').val(info.event.end.toLocaleString());
            // EXIBINDO A MODAL
            $('#visualizar').modal('show');
        },
        selectable: true,
        // SELECIONA A DATA AO CLICAR 
        select: function (info) {
            // ATRIBUINDO A DATA E HORA - INÍCIO E FIM AO FORMULÁRIO
            $('#cadastrar #DataInicial').val(info.start.toLocaleString());
            $('#cadastrar #DataFinal').val(info.end.toLocaleString());
            $('#cadastrar').modal('show');
        }
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

Após o events: tenho a chamada da página que faz o resgate dos campos postado acima e tentei resgatar algumas informações assim:

```
events: 'pListaAgendamento.php',
                 FoneResponsavel: FoneResponsavel,
                 EmailResponsavel: EmailResponsavel,
```

Tentando jogar nos  inputs assim:

```
// VALORES PARA EDIÇÃO
$('#visualizar #Id').val(info.event.id);            
$('#visualizar #Motivo').val(info.event.title);
$('#visualizar #Telefone').val(event.FoneResponsavel);
$('#visualizar #Email').val(event.EmailResponsavel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primeira negativa da pergunta me fez voltar ao inspetor do navegador e ir vendo as possibilidades do Fullcalendar, não vou excluir a pergunta mas responde-la para futuras consultas se necessário.
No inspetor encontrei a tag `extendedProps` que me exibiu os campos extras do meu formulário e ai ficou fácil de recupera-los e joga-los no formulário de edição.
O que antes era isso:

```
// VALORES PARA EDIÇÃO
$('#visualizar #Id').val(info.event.id);            
$('#visualizar #Motivo').val(info.event.title);
$('#visualizar #Telefone').val(event.FoneResponsavel);
$('#visualizar #Email').val(event.EmailResponsavel);
```

Agora ficou assim:

```
// VALORES PARA EDIÇÃO
$('#visualizar #Id').val(info.event.id);            
$('#visualizar #Motivo').val(info.event.title);
$('#visualizar #Email').val(info.event.extendedProps.EmailResponsavel);
$('#visualizar #Telefone').val(info.event.extendedProps.FoneResponsavel);
```